# How to generate strong test case for the Update Binary string problem

Tags: algorithm, hash, binary, generator, segment

Problem: I have a binary string S with a length of N and Q queries:

- Query 1: Update all elements of string S from index u to index v to be equal to x (where x is 0 or 1).
- Query 2: Check if S[x..y] is equal to S[z..t].

I'm unsure how to generate robust test cases for this problem. Could you please assist me? I attempted to use a Segment Tree or something similar. I apologize for any language errors.